# A series of properties as a map value

Tags: sass

Can an SCSS map somehow map a key to an arbitrary string of CSS properties, something like this (but this does not work):

```
$formats: (
  1: "color: red; font-size: large",
  2: "color: blue; font-weight: bold; text-align: center"
)
```

Comment: You're closing the map with `}` and not `)`. Is that a typo in your question or is it in your code too?

Comment: Typo. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think it's possible with the syntax you provided. But something like this might do the trick for you ?

```
$map: (
  foo: (
    color: .red,
    font-size: large
  ), 
  bar: (
    color: blue,
    font-weight: bold,
    text-align: center;
  )
);

@mixin print-styles($map){
 @each $property, $value in $map {
   #{$property}: $value;
 }
}

.foo {
 @include print-styles(map-get($map, foo));
}

.bar {
 @include print-styles(map-get($map, bar));
}
```

Comment: I see. Make each of the CSS property settings a key-value pair in a nested map. Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if this works with shorthand properties, such as border: 1px solid black.